# On change event Ext.form.DateField

Tags: extjs

I have a Ext.form.DateField:

```
new Ext.form.DateField({
            id: 'date_from',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            editable: false,
            listeners: {
            change: function (t,n,o) {
                console.log('dsd');
            }

        }
 })
```

However unfortunately the change event does not seem to be executed.

I have also tried:

```
new Ext.form.DateField({
            id: 'date_from',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            editable: false,
            change: function (t,n,o) {
                console.log('dsd');
            }
})
```

However also to no avail. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `change` event only fires on blur.  If you are trying to handle any date selection use the [`select`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/source/DateField.html#event-Ext.form.DateField-select) event instead (in ExtJS 3.4).

Answer (score 1):

And the first way is the correct way to add listeners.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it into :

```
new Ext.form.DateField({
            id: 'date_from',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            editable: false,
            listeners: {
            update: {
                fn:function(){
                    console.log('dsd');
                }
            }
        }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting using calendar icon then add select listener
if you are clearing datefield using backspace keys then  add change listener

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31234722)