# how to reset EXT datefield

Tags: extjs, reset, datefield

I have use two date fields as start and end date to select date range, render these date fields in two separate divs. problem is that when i press reset button date fields get reset but the calendar component is not reset and still disable all the dates outside of date range that was selected  until i refresh the page:

here its a html

```
<table cellspacing="6" align="center" border="0">           
<tr>
  <td><b>Report Period:</b> </td>
<td><div id="fromDateRange"></div></td>         
<td><div id="toDateRange"></div></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Search"/></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

here ext code

```
var drSt = new Ext.Panel({
 labelWidth: 30, 
 border: false,
 width: 100,
 layout: 'fit',
 defaults: {width: 125},
 defaultType: 'datefield',
 items: [{
 name: 'startdt',
 id: 'startdt',
 vtype: 'daterange',
 format: 'Y-m-d',
 endDateField: 'enddt' // id of the end date field
 }]
});

drSt.render('fromDateRange');

var drET = new Ext.Panel({
    labelWidth: 30,
    border: false,
    width: 100,
    layout: 'fit',        
    defaults: {width: 125},
    defaultType: 'datefield',
    items: [{
      name: 'enddt',
      id: 'enddt',    
      vtype: 'daterange',
      format: 'Y-m-d',
      startDateField: 'startdt' // id of the start date field
    }]
  });

drET.render('toDateRange');
```

Answer (score 1):

add a listener to your date field. use a select listener not a change listener as the change event only fires on blur. or you could do this

```
 dateFrom.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
         ...
    }
 });
```

to clear you can use something like this - fork to your needs

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    onTriggerClick: function() {
        Ext.form.DateField.prototype.onTriggerClick.apply(this, arguments);
        var btn = new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Clear'
        });
        btn.render(this.menu.picker.todayBtn.container);
    }
}
```

[source](http://www.verious.com/qa/ext-js-sencha-add-button-to-date-field-popup-to-clear-date/)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247948/on-change-event-ext-form-datefield for an example. You should specify the date as a datefield also

Comment: format of listener is addListener( eventName, handler, [scope], [options] ) see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.DateField

Comment: all the code you need is here http://publikz.com/blog_1223 - how about an accept?

Answer (score 0):

```
onTriggerClick: function() {
    Ext.form.DateField.prototype.onTriggerClick.apply(this, arguments);
    if(!this.hasOwnProperty('btnClear')) {
        var self = this;
        this.btnClear = new Ext.Button({
            text: _('reset'),
            listeners:{
                click: function() {
                    console.log(self)
                    self.reset()
                    self.fireEvent('select')
                }
            }
        });
        this.btnClear.render(this.menu.picker.todayBtn.container);
    }
}
```